# Can you have a universal app that targets Windows 10 and 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have a universal app for Windows 8.1 and Phone 8.1 and am looking to make the jump to Windows 10.

Looking at the guides, I need to recreate the projects, but does this mean this new project will only work on Windows 10?

What is the strategy for this setup? Keep a Windows 8.1 version and a Windows 10 version? Or does the Windows 10 version work on 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Windows 10 introduces several new API and also included old API's those work in Windows 8. but you just simply can't run Windows 10 app in Windows 8 environment.
if you look at this site: http://www.jayway.com/2015/06/16/do-windows-8-apps-run-on-windows-10/
he tells us that Win 8 app runs Win 10 but lack of some feature such as charm bar and splash screen.

of course this concerns many developer but in my honest opinion, you should just move on to developing app for windows 10. everyone will upgrade, eventually.
there's so many advantages for developing win 10 app, one of them is your app will run on broader device and market.

more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx